# Oracle SQL multiple table join returning duplicates

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

My schema is:

```
Hotel (hotelNo, hotelName, city)
Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)
Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFr, dateTo, roomNo)
Guest (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)
```

I want to display all room details and guestName if the room was occupied for the date I put in the condition for a particular hotel.

I can pull off a query to show the hotelNo, hotelName, city and guestName that meets the condition like so:

```
select h.hotelNo, h.hotelName, h.city, g.guestName 
from Hotel h
join Booking b on (h.hotelNo = b.hotelNo)
join Guest g on (b.guestNo = g.guestNo)
where h.hotelName = 'Grouse Hotel'
and TO_DATE('04-Jan-2020') between b.dateFrom and b.dateTo;
```

The above returns the one and only record that I want.

```
1   Grouse Hotel    London  Marie King
```

but when I try to now get the room info instead which is what I need, I get the same individual guest three times in the three types of room available at the Grouse Hotel.

```
select r.roomNo, r.hotelNo, r.room_type, r.price, g.guestName 
    from Room r
    join Hotel h on (h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo)
    join Booking b on (r.hotelNo = b.hotelNo)
    join Guest g on (b.guestNo = g.guestNo)
    where TO_DATE('04-Jan-2020') between b.dateFrom and b.dateTo
    and h.hotelName = 'Grouse Hotel';
```

returns

```
1   1   single  120 Marie King
2   1   double  200 Marie King
3   1   suite   500 Marie King
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query misses a join condition between the booking and the room, so it associates each booking to all rooms in the related hotel.

Consider:

```
select r.roomNo, r.hotelNo, r.room_type, r.price, g.guestName 
from Room r
join Hotel h   on h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo
join Booking b on r.hotelNo = b.hotelNo and r.roomNo = b.roomNo
join Guest g   on b.guestNo = g.guestNo    --^-- here
where 
    b.dateFrom <= DATE'2020-01-04' and b.dateTo >= DATE'2020-01-04'
    and h.hotelName = 'Grouse Hotel';
```

Note that I rewrote your `where` clause so it allows the database to take advantage of an index involving the date columns, if any.

Comment: I edited the hotel name in the second query to reflect the correct name.